# Upper Semi-Continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be any real function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and let:

$\phi(x, \delta)=sup\{|f(s)-f(t)|: s,t \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)\} $

$\phi (x)= inf \{ \phi (x,\delta): \delta > 0 \}$

Show that $\phi$ is upper semi-continuous.

I know that $\phi$ is upper semi-continuous if $\limsup_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)\leq f(x_0)  $ .
But I don't know how to show that the $\phi$ is upper continuous. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I did using the definition of upper semi-continuous giving by:

$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta$ such that, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|x-x_0| <\delta \Rightarrow \phi (x) \leq \phi(x_0)+ \epsilon$

My proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

$\phi (x_0)= inf\{\phi (x_0, \delta): \delta >0\}$, by the definition of inf, for $\epsilon$ given we have a $\delta_1$ such that:

$\phi (x_0) \leq \phi(x_0, \delta_1) \leq \phi (x_0)+ \epsilon$

Let $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0+\delta)$.

Let $\delta_2=min \{|x_0-x|,|x-x_0+\delta_1|,|x_0+\delta_1-x|\}$.

It is clear that: $\phi (x,\delta_2) \leq \phi (x_0,\delta_1)$.

But we see that $\phi (x)= inf \phi (x, \delta: \delta>0)$.

Then $\phi (x) \leq \phi (x_0, \delta)$.

By the previous inequality we conclude $\phi (x) \leq \phi(x_0)+ \epsilon$